# RichTextBox прорисовка как у TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю совтину. Столкнулся с следующей проблемой: нужно, чтобы на форме был `RichTextBox`, который обнесен черной тонкой сплошной линией. Т.е он должен выглядеть как `TextBox` c `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D` или как `TextBox` c `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle`

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только ручная отрисовка, либо использование системного UXTheme/Visual Styles API:

- [Themed RichTextBox - A RichTextBox with XP-styled borders](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13723/Themed-RichTextBox-A-RichTextBox-with-XP-styled-bo)
- [Rich Text Box Border Style](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fedffcb7-c4f0-4b50-bafb-605ef8bdaf28/rich-text-box-border-style)

Второй пример из коробки не компилируется, закинул на [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/unHWqNtS) рабочую версию. Там готовый контрол, можно через свойства указать толщину и цвет границы.

Comment: 1 - то, что надо. Только границу можно ли там темнее сделать?
2 - не компилируется.

Comment: @Janycz: Вы о втором примере? Там код не полный. Нет импорта некоторых функций. Сейчас скину полный.

Comment: Спасибо. 2 вариант пашет как надо.